# Counting number of observation within time interval

Tags: r, datetime

I have data with `str` of `POSIXct`. 
For each observation I want to count the number of observations which preceded this observation in time intervals of 6 and 24 hours (the time intervals need to be flexible).

Here some reproducible example:

```
Dat <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=as.POSIXct(c("2017-02-01 16:05:35", "2017-02-01 16:15:35", "2017-02-01 18:15:37", "2017-02-01 23:30:35", "2017-02-02 01:15:35")))
```

And I'd like to get the following output:

```
x v6 v24
1   --  --
2   1   1
3   2   2
4   1   3
5   1   4
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably more efficient ways exist, but this should work

```
Dat <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=as.POSIXct(c("2017-02-01 16:05:35", "2017-02-01 16:15:35", "2017-02-01 18:15:37", 
                                    "2017-02-01 23:30:35", "2017-02-01 01:15:35")))

Dat <- Dat[order(Dat[,"y"]),]

require(lubridate)

Dat[,"span6"] <- Dat[,"y"] - hours(6)
Dat[,"span24"] <- Dat[,"y"] - hours(24)

for(s in Dat[,"span6"]){
  Dat[which(Dat[,"span6"]==s),"v6"] <-
    nrow(Dat[which(Dat[,"y"]>=s & Dat[,"y"]<Dat[which(Dat[,"span6"]==s),"y"]),])
}
for(s in Dat[,"span24"]){
  Dat[which(Dat[,"span24"]==s),"v24"] <-
    nrow(Dat[which(Dat[,"y"]>=s & Dat[,"y"]<Dat[which(Dat[,"span24"]==s),"y"]),])
}
Dat <- Dat[,!(names(Dat) %in% c("span6","span24"))]
```

Comment: It does look clumsy, but works perfectly! Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

You might try that way, with `library(sqldf)`.
I try to get you a simple example using your data:

```
library(sqldf)

Dat <- data.frame(x=1:5, y=c("2017-02-01 16:05:35", "2017-02-01 16:15:35", "2017-02-01 18:15:37", "2017-02-01 23:30:35", "2017-02-01 01:15:35"))

sqldf('select distinct count (x) as count, 
       x
       from Dat 
       where y between "2017-02-01 16:05:35" and "2017-02-01 18:15:35"
       group by x')
```

The output is as follows:

```
  count x
1     1 1
2     1 2
```

You get a count of how many x values ​​are in the range expressed by

`where y between "2017-02-01 16:05:35" and "2017-02-01 18:15:35"`

The extremes of the range are included in the count.
Is the Correct Solution For your Problem?

Comment: @G.Grothendieck you have tried my code? Because I have tried it and written so it works!

Comment: @G.Grothendieck yes sorry because I forgot to delete of the code  
    as.POSIXct(). It work only without as.POSIXct()

Comment: It works now but I would recommend using single quotes around the literal dates in which case it would also work with the H2 backend as well.  Also it would then work with the H2 backend even if y is POSIXct.

Comment: @LorenzoBenassi Thank you very much for your effort, but it doesn't really answer my question. For example, there's no reference in your answer to the time interval I specified in my question.

Comment: @staove7 you can express the time interval entering date and time where the interval begins and end using the statement between